# GTK# - Problem with components overlapping upon resize

Tags: gtk#

I have a panel containing a form (elements such as labels and textboxes within a table) and 3 buttons (in an hbuttonbox) at the bottom-right.  If I shorten the panel by dragging the bottom border upwards, the 3 buttons come with it, and lay on top of the other form components, causing messy graphics. I would like the panel to not resize smaller than the bottom edge of the last component within it. Due to employer restrictions, I am not able to show a screenshot of the GUI. I will try to make any clarifications that are asked.

This probably has something to do with some resizing or general size settings on the components, but there are so many options that I'm not sure where to start.

Any ideas for an easy fix to this without getting down into the complicated nest of components? If not, any ideas on where I should start messing with settings?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
Everything is contained in a VBox with 3 cells. Elements in cells (top to bottom): Table, ScrolledWindow, HButtonBox.  The ScrolledWindow bottom edge also moves (resizes) with the bottom edge of the panel when resizing, until the panel bottom goes above the whole ScrolledWindow. Then the buttons keep moving up, staying in relation to the panel's bottom edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a Height Request to the container, just slightly longer than the part of the scrolled window.  This now stops resizing to where the bottom buttons would overlap the components above it.  The problem (before the fix) is shown below:

[image: Regular Sized Panel]

[image: Resized with overlap]

Answer (score 0):

By "form" do you mean you are using a `Gtk.Fixed` to contain your table and buttonbox? Then that's probably what's going wrong - you should use vboxes and hboxes for your layout. These will resize properly. Fixed layouts are only for exceptional cases.

**EDIT**:

Other suggestions:

- Perhaps the `HButtonBox` has pack type 'end' instead of 'start'?
- You could try playing with the 'fill' and 'expand' packing properties of the VBox's children.

Comment: No, everything is placed with Vboxes and Hboxes. Both the table and hbuttonbox are in a Vbox (same vbox, diff cells). The vbox has 3 elements added to it: Table, GtkScrolledWindow, and Hbuttonbox.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you make a layout with unrelated components and post a screenshot or code of that, without violating your employer's restrictions?

Comment: I tried making the HButtonBox has pack type 'start' and also messing around with the fill and expand options on everything, but I could not find a combo that worked. However, I just made an edit above with the solution or workaround for my problem that I found. Thanks!